# Unitriangular matrix group is nilpotent

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $N_i$ be the subset of matrices in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & * & \cdots & *\\
  & \ddots & \ddots & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  &        & \ddots & \ddots & & \ddots & \ast\\
  &        &        & \ddots & \ddots & & 0\\
 & & & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
& & & & & \ddots & 0\\
& & & & & & 1
\end{bmatrix}

and the end of zero the first line is at column $i$.
That is, there are $i-1$ zeros in a line except for the Lower triangular.

(1) prove $N_i$ is a group.

(2) prove $[N_1, N_i] \subset N_{i+1}$.

(3) prove $N_1$ is nilpotent

I am trying this problem and proved (1), but I'm having trouble proving (2) and (3).

My work on (2) is following.

- $ABA^{-1}B^{-1} = AB\widetilde{AB}$. ($\widetilde{A}$ is adjugate matrix of A)
- I tried to compute component of $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$, but it is too complex.

Please some ideas or solutions. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $N_i$. Also, please share your work on (2) and (3).

Comment: What's the parameter $i$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've revised the question and added my attempt.

Comment: (3) follows immediately from (2)

Comment: For (2) it might be easier to compare the actions of $AB$ and $BA$ on the basis vectors.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thankyou! I try to compute this with $(XBA)_{j,k} = (AB)_{j,k}\ (X \in [N_1, N_{i}])$. but it is still complex for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in $N_1$ stabilize a chain $\{0\}=V_0 < V_1 < V_2 < \cdots V_n = V$ of subspaces of the space on which it is acting, with $\dim(V_i) = i$.

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be the natural basis of $V$, so $v_k \in V_k \setminus V_{k-1}$.

Elements $A$ of $N_1$ satisfy $A(v_k) = v_k + x$ with $x \in V_{k-1}$.

Elements $B$ of $N_i$ satisfy $B(v_k) = v_k + y$ with $y \in V_{k-i}$ (replace $k-i$ by $0$ when negative).

So $BA(v_k) = B(v_k+x) = v_k + x + y + z$ with $x \in V_{k-1}$, $y \in V_{k-i}$, $z \in V_{k-i-1}$.

$AB(v_k) = A(v_k+y) = v_k+x+y+z'$ with $z' \in V_{k-i-1}$.

These differ only by elements of $V_{k-i-1}$, so $AB = CBA$ where $C(v_k) = v_k + t$ for some $t \in V_{k-i-1}$, which proves (2).

Comment: Thank you ! I learned an important perspective from your answer !